# Error producing PDF. ! LaTeX Error: File `biblatex.sty' not found

Tags: biblatex

I use tex for converting reports from markdown to pdf. I didn't use it 2 month and it doesn't work anymore. I reinstalled already 5 times. Nothing works. I'm still have this mistake `Error producing PDF.! LaTeX Error: File 'biblatex.sty' not found.` when I try to convert `arch -x86_64 pandoc report1.md -o report1.pdf`. I'm a mac user. Advices for linux don't work too. Please help me to fix it!![image]

Comment: Reinstalled exactly what? Which LaTeX installation have you installed? Please be specific.

Comment: I got mactex from web site https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

Comment: Well do not wildly reinstall if you run into a problem that you don't understand.  Beside this you should be able to install biblatex with `tlmgr install biblatex`.

Comment: "tlmgr itself needs to be updated.
Please do this via either
  tlmgr update --self" Should I do it or not?

Comment: I updated and did `tlmgr install biblatex`. It still doesn't work

Comment: Do you by any change have two latex installations? What does `which pdflatex` say?

Comment: `/opt/local/bin/pdflatex`

Comment: If you installed the full MacTeX then `biblatex` is included in it and the latex call should not complain about a missing `biblatex.sty`. Can you get pandoc to leave the latex file and then compile the latex file by hand, just to see the difference.

Comment: That sounds odd, with MacTeX I'd expect it to say something like containing `texbin`. What does `pdflatex --version` say?

Comment: Sorry, idk how to do it

Comment: run `pdflatex --version` just like you just ran `which pdflatex`

Comment: `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/MacPorts 2023.66589_1)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.40; using libpng 1.6.40
Compiled with zlib 1.3; using zlib 1.3
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04`

Comment: Then you have two latex installations the one from MacTeX and one from MacPorts.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: The MacTeX one have probably not installed everything and as far as I remember for MacPort you cannot use `tlmgr` to update/install packages.

Comment: I don't use Mac, sorry. If you also installed the one from MacPorts, I'd removed what one as MacTeX includes **everything**.

Comment: How can I remove MacPorts version?

Comment: Maybe give https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95783/how-can-i-uninstall-the-macports-tex-packages a try. (I don't know how up-to-date this is, I haven't use macports since ages...)

Comment: You seem to have Macports installed `/opt/local/bin` is its default installation path. Macports installs TexLive frequently as it's a dependency of various things. You can check by doing `echo $PATH`. I suspect you'll find `/opt/local/bin` in there. You need to remove it from you path (check your ~/.zshrc).

Comment: I did `echo $PATH` and get a long messeage:

Comment: /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/

Comment: MacOS:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin

Comment: How can I remove it?

Comment: why does the path begin with texlive/2013? Do you really have such an old texlive?

Comment: I could fix it. Now I have other error

Comment: Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character т (U+0442)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: That is a different issue that warrants a new question. In that new question you should include a small example document that you tried to compile and that reproduces the error you are asking about.